# Implementing Android Auto voice command support

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, android-auto

I am working on implementing voice commands for Android Auto using media player callback methods. I am having trouble getting Auto to recognize that I am asking to play a title on my application: `“Play [x] on MyApp”`. I understand that it takes a few days after being published for this command to work, but I should still be able to say `“Play [x]”` while the media session is already running and it should use `onPrepareFromSearch` and `onPlayFromSearch` methods to search for and play content.

When I say `“Play [x] on MyApp”` I get the response `“I looked for [x] on MyApp on Google Play Music but it either isn’t available or it can’t be played right now”`.
When I say `“Play [x]”` while my media service is running it will usually redirect me to Google Play Music.

I am able to pause, resume, skip forward and skip backward using voice commands and I see those being logged but when I try to perform a voice search neither `onPrepareFromSearch` nor `onPlayFromSearch` are called.

Things I have tried:

- Added an `<intent-filter>` for `MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH` to an activity in my application as to mark my application available to search for media
- Implemented `onPrepareFromSearch` and `onPlayFromSearch` in my `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`
- Added `ACTION_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH` and `ACTION_PREPARE_FROM_SEARCH` as supported actions.
- Set the media session flags `FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS` and `FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS`
- Added support for Android Auto as per the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto

Is there a step I am missing in order to get this to work?

Comment: Hello. It might be connected to [this](https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/17637015) and [this](https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/14046486) 

As far as I know it is not entirely fixed yet.

Comment: did you find a solution ?